# Как расположить элемент с помощью абсолютного позиционирования

Tags: html, css, адаптивность

Я пытаюсь использовать абсолютное позиционирование, но у меня не получается. Есть иконка корзины и рядом с ней цифр (кол-во товара) и мне нужно эту цифру сдвинуть левее чтобы она была более видна. Класс - `number`

**html**

```
<div class="cart_block">
    {% if cart %}
        <div id="cart_score">
            <span class="number">{{cart.get_length}}</span>
            <span class="cart_text">товаров - {{cart.get_total_price}} &#8381;</span>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div id="cart_score">
            <span class="cart_text">Корзина пуста</span>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**css**

```
.cart_block {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 210px;
    height: 40px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    background: url("{% static 'cart.png' %}") no-repeat 5%;
}

@media (max-width: 760px) {
    .cart_block {
        padding-left: 33px;
        width: 0;
    }

    .cart_text {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Пример для наглядности. Цифра расположена в не очень видном месте. Хотелось бы поставить ее левее.

[image: example]

Пробовал писать так, но не выходит.

```
.number {
    position: absolute;
    padding-right: 33px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А если к примеру цифру обернуть в блок расположить абсолютно и залить фоном, явно акцентным , к примеру вот так

> Пример кода НЕ открывать на весь экран

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@media(max-width:768px) {
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .top {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 60px;
  }
  span.trigger {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }
  span.trigger i {
    display: block;
    width: 45px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 6px auto;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 11;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #fff;
  }
  .menu a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  h2,
  .fas {
    font-size: 34px;
  }
  h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: blue;
  }
  .basket {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .fas.fa-shopping-basket {
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: #ccc;
  }
  i#num {
    color: #fff;
    background: tomato;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css">

<div class="top">
  <span class="trigger">
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
  </span>
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#">Сcылка1</a>
    <a href="#">Сcылка2</a>
    <a href="#">Сcылка3</a>
    <a href="#">Сcылка4</a>
    <a href="#">Сcылка5</a>
  </div>
  <h2>case moscow</h2>
  <p class="basket">
    <i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i>
    <i id="num" class="number">3</i>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте (если это позволяет ваша разметка) решить проблему с помощью позиционирования. Элемент с `position: absolute` можно спозиционировать относительно родителя, если у родителя стоит `position: relative` (https://webref.ru/course/position/relative-absolute).

В вашем случае можно разместить саму цифру (`.number`) относительно контейнера, в котором она находится (`#cart-score`):

```
#cart_score {
    position: relative;
}

#cart-score .number {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;  /*значения top и left можете подобрать самостоятельно*/
    left: 5px;  /*в зависимости от желаемого положения цифры*/
}
```